# What is the purpose of God?

Tags: allah, creation

I understand what Islam says about the purpose of our life. It's to be tested.

But I've never heard anyone talk about the purpose of God. What's his purpose? Is his purpose solely to test us? Is all the beauty of his creation and that of the hereafter solely so that we can be tested?

I find that notion to be very disrespectful to the mightiness of God, but I can't find an alternate answer. And strangely, no one talks about it.

(EDIT: This question is usually avoided by saying "Oh, you can't understand the nature of God. It's beyond your comprehension". I find that to be very unfair. Why am I given the ability to ask what the purpose of God is but not the ability to understand the answer to that question).

Comment: Purpose is a human concept

Comment: Allah is the creator of the Whole World. And He is the fist and last. I don't see any benefit of asking such question. Suppose I answered you that, _the purpose of the God (Allah) is to create the creations ( and test them), and Allah knows better_. **Could you kindly inform me what is the benefit you've achieved**? Look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flZFCxbKZvU)  is might lead you to the correct way.

Comment: If your answer is that God's purpose is to test us, then I'd say either your answer is wrong or the God you believe in doesn't exist. Because the purpose you supposedly attribute to God seems like a very silly thing to do. Why test someone when you know the result?

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of God is to be.... well, God. To do whatever He wants.

No one talks about it because "purpose" applies to what is created with a reason in mind (eg, humans created by God to worship, camels created by God for riding, pens created by humans for writing, nests created by birds for sheltering their eggs, etc). **It is not applicable to God since no one created Him with an intent in mind**. -- So you cannot try to force a question when it doesn't apply to begin with.

@"*Is his purpose solely to test us*?" - No. An analogy, that's like saying because you eat then that your purpose is to eat. It's just an action; not something that defines you.

Thus, that (i.e, testing us) is not a purpose. It is a desire. This is something He wishes to do. It is not something He has to do nor something that is expected from him to do because NO ONE lays any expectations on Him. This is what you need to understand then it will make sense.

Answer (score 1):

God cannot have a purpose because a purpose is a given limitation. Who would give a purpose and a limit to God? **God is without limit and without any higher authority, and therefore the concept of purpose does not apply to Him.**

If that doesn't make sense to you or you think it is not reasonable, then the reason for you thinking like that is due to your thinking being influenced by all the created things you see around you. When we look around us, everything has a purpose. This applies to all created things and naturally has to, as God defined a purpose and limit for them all. To apply this to the Creator is an error in your understanding of the meaning of "purpose".

Comment: I don't agree that God is without limit. God can't cheat, he can't lie, he can't create another God, he can't be unjust.

If God can have limits, why can't he be limited by purpose?